# QGIS labels aren't controlled by themes

Tags: qgis, labeling

I love themes in QGIS. I also love how I can create multiple symbologies for a layer and that these can be controlled by themes. Even better is the fact that layouts can follow themes. Unless I am missing something, I don't see where any of that functionality is available in ArcGIS Pro.

Has anyone come up with a way to control labeling with a theme?

If I have a label style for each symbology, the only way I can control which label style is displaying is to check/uncheck the styles as needed. The only way I can get what I want is to duplicate the layer as many times as needed, creating one label style per layer.   I did come up with a work-around but it's clunky and difficult to maintain, at best.

I have submitted this as a feature request.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign several styles to a layer.

Set up one style with labeling and setup others without labelling or make any settings change you wish.

The theme will then store the layer-style combo of your choice.

Comment: Thank you, Snaileater. I haven’t investigated styles, despite knowing of that feature, and absolutely depending on styles when doing layouts in InDesign (my favorite programs: InDesign and QGIS, which I sort of think of as InDesign for GIS). I have to investigate.